# MySQL. Как получить UTC timestamp из колонки Datetime

Tags: mysql, timestamp

1. На сервере установлен часовой пояс GMT-7, и нет возможности его изменить.
2. Есть колонка DateTime, в которой лежит "2016-03-03"
3. Нужно получить timestamp, считая, что в колонке лежит время в UTC.

UNIX_TIMESTAMP выдаёт 1456963200, вместо 1456988400 (разница 25200 = 7 часов).

Как решить?

Answer (score 1):

Тип DATETIME хранит дату-время в локальном часовом поясе.

Если вы будете использовать поле типа TIMESTAMP, то там значение хранится в UTC и `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tsfield)` будет давать целочисленное представление без поясного сдвига.

Альтернативно вы можете установить "сессионный часовой пояс" в начале сеанса:

```
SET @@session.time_zone='+00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему только харкодить это смещение при запросах:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetimefield + INTERVAL 2520 SECOND);
```